# How to make selenium Chromedriver run headlessly in VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I've written some code in vba in combination with selenium to parse some movie titles and the year of its release from a torrent site. I used `ChromeDriver` in my scraper. When I execute my script, It does parse the required fields.

Now, my question is: how can i make it `headless`? In other languages there are the options which can be added to the driver to do the trick like below:

```
chrome_options = Options
chrome_options.add_argument ("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument ("--window-size=2160,3840")
driver = WebDriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

When It comes to add the options to vba to make it headless, I get stuck.

This is my basic approach (It's a working one but browser is visible):

```
Sub Demo_Test()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    driver.get "https://yts.am/browse-movies"

    For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("browse-movie-bottom")
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.FindElementByClass("browse-movie-title").Text
        Cells(r, 2) = post.FindElementByClass("browse-movie-year").Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Any help on making the script run headless, will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try  `driver.AddArgument "--headless"`, then call `driver.get "https://yts.am/browse-movies"`

Comment: Thanks Florent B., for such an wonderful solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I should keep this post open when I've already got the working solution in comment by `Florent B.` This is how we can make `ChromeDriver` run headlessly.

The full script:

```
Sub Demo_Test()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .AddArgument "--headless"   ''This is the fix
        .get "https://yts.am/browse-movies"
    End With

    For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("browse-movie-bottom")
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.FindElementByClass("browse-movie-title").Text
        Cells(r, 2) = post.FindElementByClass("browse-movie-year").Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Comment: When using driver.AddArgument "--headless" then driver.FindElementByClass and also  driver.IsElementPresen don't work. Without the AddArgument it works ok. what should I do?

Comment: Is this still working with chrome driver v 109? It seems to have no impact of the browser.